# What's CART_SESSION_ID holding?

Tags: python, django

I am following Django by example book. In settings.py

`CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'`

in cart.py in cart app

````
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
    """
    Initialize the cart.
    """
    self.session = request.session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    if not cart:
        # save an empty cart in the session
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart```
````

if its a string then if not cart: block will never execute. i am unable to understand how CART_SESSION_ID is working here?

Answer (score 1):

`cart` is the result of getting the value `CARD_SESSION_ID` from dict session, not `settings.CARD_SESSION_ID` itself.

`setting.CARD_SESSION_ID` is just the key used to find a value in the `session` dict. So, the code could have been written this way :

```py
self.session = request.session
cart = self.session.get('cart')
if not cart:
    # save an empty cart in the session
    cart = self.session['cart'] = {}
    self.cart = cart``
```

(Of course you should use the code from the documentation since it's way more consistent)

Comment: Yeah. But we defined  ```CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart``` before. then is it a string? if it is then why if not cart: block executing?

Comment: In your exemple, variable `cart` is not `settings.CART_SESSION_ID` but `self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)` which is not the same thing. I updated a little bit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. In my ```settings.py``` ```CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart' ```. Here is ```'cart'``` is session key or something like this? or just a string.

Comment: Please read Django session documentation if you want more information about this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/http/sessions/